# Реализация вступления в группу ВК

Tags: php, vkontakte-api

В общем, захотелось сделать на PHP штуку, которая вступает в мою группу при авторизации пользователя.
То есть схема такая

> -> сайт -> авторизация -> я шлю запрос API ВК и пользователь ,который
>   авторизовался попадает в группу.

Сразу после написания кода - тестировал и ничего не хочет работать. ВК возвращает ошибку что необходимо что-то подтвердить. 
Вот -

```
"error":{"error_code":17,"error_msg":"Validation required: please open redirect_uri in browser xxx","request_params":[{"key":"oauth","value":"1"},{"key":"method","value":"groups.invite"},{"key":"group_id","value":"112450248"},{"key":"user_id","value":"146763854"},{"key":"v","value":"5.44"}],"redirect_uri":"https:\/\/m.vk.com\/login?act=security_check&api_hash=d8fc4ee30acc82f9c3"}}
```

Посоветуйте, как это решить(с примерами желательно) - возможно необходимо использовать OPEN API...
И ещё скажу что использую Standalone приложения и как-то вообще никак без него там вступление в группы.Сам ВК не позволяет.

Ссылка на код:
   http://pastebin.com/5yHi7EKH

```
function CodeGet($code,$client,$secret){
    $tok = "https://oauth.vk.com/access_token?client_id=$client&client_secret=$secret&redirect_uri=http://lend.sloadme.ru&code=$code";
    $tok = file_get_contents($tok);
    $tok = json_decode($tok);
    $tok = $tok->access_token;
    return $tok;
}
function SendAPI($token){
    $groupd_id = '112450248';
    $surl = "https://api.vk.com/method/groups.invite?group_id=$groupd_id&user_id=146763854&v=5.44&access_token=$token";
    echo $surl;
    $surl = file_get_contents($surl);
    echo $surl;


}
$skey = 'секрет кей';
$id = 'ид прилоги'';
$lurl = "https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=$id&display=page&redirect_uri=http://lend.sloadme.ru&scope=friends,groups&response_type=code&v=5.44";

$tok = $_GET['code'];
 if ($tok) {
    $token = CodeGet($tok,$id,$skey);
    SendAPI($token); 
     }
```

Скорее всего надо перенаправлять юзера на служебную страницу,но как потом забрать данные - я не знаю

Comment: Вы что-то не понимаете и не то делаете..... standalone  он только для каких-нибудь андройд приложений... а php - это вы, веб делаете..... а там авторизация `Oauth`.... а вы пытаетесь авторизоваться через `curl` небось...... а авторизация через `Oauth` подразумевается, что в начале открывается окно, в котором пользователь должен подтвердить вход, в ведя данные, после этого эти данные идут к вам с необходимыми параметрами для авторизации.. показывайте как вы делаете авторизацию.. код

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский Добавил код.Так я так и делал - это вк что-то творит

Comment: Ошибка пояснение https://vk.com/dev/need_validation ..... а вообще тут как раз несоответствие. У вас не `standalone` приложение..... а вступление в группу доступно только Standalone-приложениям. https://vk.com/dev/groups.invite  .... несостыковочка

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский Всмысле?У меня как раз Standalone - тип.Я все прекрасно понимаю что выбирал  - иначе никак

Comment: Покажите ссылку на тот метод авторизации, что вы используете

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский Раз (это токен после получения кода)  `$tok = "https://oauth.vk.com/access_token?client_id=$client&client_secret=$secret&redirect_uri=http://lend.sloadme.ru&code=$code";
    $tok = file_get_contents($tok);` и это код `https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?client_id=$id&display=page&redirect_uri=http://lend.sloadme.ru&scope=friends,groups&response_type=code&v=5.44` Не по порядку(пишу с телефона)

Comment: Я про ссылку в vk/dev ....... `&code=$code` вроде не используется в standalone

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский Oauth есть там метод -  http://vk.com/dev/standalone

Comment: В САМ МЕТОД дайте ссылку В то что вы используете. где описываются эти параметры и как авторизация проходит

Comment: https://vk.com/dev/auth_sites  оно?  или https://vk.com/dev/auth_mobile оно?

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский Да,первое

Comment: А теперь внимательно перейдите на шаг назад (https://vk.com/dev/authentication) и посмотрите ....первая ссылка - `Серверная авторизация для подключения сайтов`.... вторая ссылка - `Клиентская авторизация для Standalone-приложений`... вы все еще утверждаете, что у вас `standalone` ?

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский То есть получается - нужно было клиентский метод авторизации использовать?Если да,то извините меня.

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский Появилась новая проблема,эх - http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/485491/%d0%92%d0%9a-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d1%83-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bf%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b5-%d0%b2%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b2-%d0%b3%d1%80%d1%83%d0%bf%d0%bf%d1%83