# Ошибка «Access denied» при попытке вступить в группу ВК

Tags: javascript, vkontakte-api

Ошибка такая:

> Access denied: no access to call this method

URL, по которому переходит пользователь, и отдаёт нам доступ или токен:

```
https://oauth.vk.com/authorize?сlient_id=$id&display=page&redirect_uri=http://lend.sloadmx.xx&scope=friends,groups,video&response_type=token&v=5.44
```

Скрипт, который отправляет данные методу и принимает ответы:

```
var get = location.hash.split('=')[1];
var get = get.split('&')[0]; // получаем access_token

if (get) {
  function callbackFunc(result) {
    console.log(result.error.error_msg);
  }    

  var url = "https://api.vk.com/method/groups.join?group_id=112450248&v=5.44&access_token=" + get;
  var script = document.createElement('SCRIPT');

  script.src = url + "&callback=callbackFunc";

  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(script);    
};
```

[Этот же код на Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/659r2jPw).

Скорее всего, если использовать Standalone-приложения, то только вкупе с OPEN API.

Но уж очень меня напрягает там всё это дело, где можно его включить в настройках, и появится список с REDIRECT URL и так далее. Тем не менее для других методов нельзя никак вообще, походу, со своим URL.

Для этого никакого REDIRECT URL не существует, похоже, и документация врёт.

Comment: `redirect_uri` должен быть равен `https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html`, см. https://vk.com/dev/auth_mobile

Comment: @Maksym Возможно гибрид использования методов из open api и такой авторизации не получится (тем более open api не использует access_token). Только используя `blank.html` - А это java для android и прочее. Т.к. документация немного не впорядке у вконтактчиков, думаю, стоит у них спросить об этом.

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский Скорее всего.Но я надеюсь что вконтактчики не настолько идиоты чтобы пихать в приложение возможность настроить OPEN API.Эх,иду играться

Comment: @Maksym на сколько пробовал лично я, после использования `VK.Auth.login(function(response) {` с настройками (правами) `262146` (что соответствует `scope=friends,groups`), то после авторизации при запросе `VK.Api.call('groups.invite` все равно будет выбивать `Access denied`

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский Не знаете где их можно спросить об этом?Это ни в какие ворота не лезет(

Comment: @Maksym В поддержке ж очевидно ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Maksym Вы как обзаведетесь новой информацией по вопросу - напишите, возможно даже ответом. Что типа и правда документация не правильная и т.д. Чтоб другие люди тоже знали в чем в итоге проблема  была/есть

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский Читайте ответ,все самим поймёте.Спасибо за помощь)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообщем, отписал в поддержку ВК.Сначала долго отвечали,но в итоге сказали,что нельзя использовать такие методы на сайтах. То есть методы, которые требуют Standalone не будут работать. Например `groups.join`

Варианта вижу три:

1.Делать десктоп приложение

2.Попытаться обойти.Я пытался,нет успеха. (например украсть URL с токеном)

3.Забить на ВК

Кстати,есть вопрос,а почему не работало то?

1.Необходимо в `REDIRECT URL` указывать дефолтный URL. `oauth.vk.com/blank.htmk`

2.Для этих методов рекомендуется использовать клиентскую авторизацию

3.Для отправки запросов на вступление и так далее,необходимо делать через IP пользователя.
Иначе выскочит ошибка.То есть левые IP -нельзя.Используйте либо браузерный JS / ...

4.Обязательно STANDALONE приложение должно быть

5. Не объязательно, но все же -  в настройках есть OPEN API и разные параметры. Рекомендуется их заполнить ,если вы собираетесь делать не только к `декстоп` методам

Буду рад, если кто-то захочет попытаться посоветовать в комментариях,как обойти это дело.Тут правда спрашивал(но мало кто меня понял),а на другом ресурсе при указании что и как я хочу - сказали что никак.Скорее всего нельзя,но вдруг....

Comment: Никак не обойти это приложением для сайта. Сделано специально, чтобы не было "левых" подписок от имени пользователя. Можно делать через blank.html и просить пользователя вставлять полученную ссылку с токеном в поле и выдирать этот токен, но это убого.

Comment: @Maksym  ответ и верен и не верен)) Например `Использовать клиентскую авторизацию` - не совсем то. Т.к. клиентская авторизация это значит на `javascript` можно сделать. 
А это не так потому, что `Для отправки запросов на вступление и так далее,необходимо делать через IP пользователя`. Поэтому тут пункт должен быть  с пометкой `Standalone`... Не смотря на то, что в доках написано, что `redirect_uri`  можно писать `если обращаетесь к API с внешнего сайта, необходимо указывать ссылку в рамках домена`. 
То есть доки явно лгут и надо вконтатчикам еще сказать чтоб они исправили..

Comment: @Maksym `4.STANDALONE - тип должен быть` тоже надо понимать и пометить..... тип типом, но в настройках приложения даже если приложение `Standalone` - можно указать способ работы: `Open API` и прописать сайт с которого хочешь работать - все равно не будет работать)))
В целом нужно четкое ограничение. **1** Документация лжет (О чем я и говорил). **2** Под `Standalone` понимается именно приложение, которое может быть "выдано" одно непосредственно "в руки клиенту".
В общем об это всем мы сразу и сказали в комментах))

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский Там есть это: `redirect_uri=https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html 
Это обязательное условие для работы с методами, в описании которых указано, что они доступны только для Desktop-приложений.`Не точно,но это есть пояснение почему так.

Comment: @Maksym нет. смотрите: https://vk.com/dev/auth_mobile  `redirect_uri -  Адрес, на который будет переадресован пользователь после прохождения авторизации (домен должен быть указан в поле «Базовый домен» в настройках приложения; адрес полностью должен быть указан в поле «Доверенный Redirect URI» в настройках приложения).` а ниже `Если Вы разрабатываете браузерное Javascript-приложение(обращаетесь к API с внешнего сайта), надо указывать ссылку в рамках домена,указанного в настройках приложения.В остальных случаях в качестве redirect_uri нужно использовать адрес https://oauth.vk.com/blank.html`

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский Ну а эти методы как раз для других платформ. Просто они сначала написали одно, потом другое и запутались

Comment: @Maksym Скорее всего раньше можно было, а потом ограничили, но забыли доки исправить... что не удивительно. это у них там во многом проявляется......Собссн я поэтому  и говорю, что ответ почти ответ)) что исходя из доков стоило бы в ответ уточнить все эти нюансы))

Comment: @Алексей Шиманский Хотел бы с вами связаться и кое-что обсудить по поводу небольшого обмана логики ВК .Вы не против?Можете дать контакты или отписать на почту `Somerrk(гав)yandex.ru`

Answer (score 1):

Вы читали [документацию](https://vk.com/dev/groups.join) по этому методу?

Данный метод доступен только Standalone-приложениям.

Comment: У них документация вся через *опу. Написано `redirect_uri - Адрес, на который будет переадресован пользователь после прохождения авторизации (домен должен быть указан в поле «Базовый домен» в настройках приложения; адрес полностью должен быть указан в поле «Доверенный Redirect URI» в настройках приложения).` Хотя это не работает. Работает только `blank.html`

Comment: Читал.Понимал что делаю.Приложение - Standalone.

Comment: права groups есть?

Comment: @IEVGEN Есть,как видите в первом URL